# Post an id in edit action to postback edit action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public ActionResult 

    Edit(int id, string ContentId)
                {
                    return View(obj.FindCommentsById(id));
                }
```

In this action i get a **contentId** and i want to transfer this id to my **postback edit action**.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Comment comment)
    {
        //comment.AutherUserName = "admin";
        //comment.LikeCount = 0;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TryUpdateModel(comment, new string[] {"CommentText", "Visible"});
          //  obj.Update(comment);
            obj.Save();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Comment", new { contentID = ContentId });
    }
```

Because as you see i need this value to redirect to **Index action** after completing .

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ViewBag`, place **ContentId** in **ViewBag** in you Edit get action like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string ContentId)
            {
                ViewBag.ContentId = ContentId
                return View(obj.FindCommentsById(id));
            }
```

in your Edit **View** add a hidden field in the Edit form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ContentId" value="@ViewBag.ContentId"/>
```

In your post action of Edit, read it from **FormCollection** and pass it to Index action parameters:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Comment comment,FormCollection form)
    {
        //comment.AutherUserName = "admin";
        //comment.LikeCount = 0;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TryUpdateModel(comment, new string[] {"CommentText", "Visible"});
          //  obj.Update(comment);
            obj.Save();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Comment", new { contentID = form["ContentId"].ToString()});
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: see the updated answer, hope you will get understanding of it

Comment: after click on edit button i redirected to this url and the contentid doesn't return :localhost:33978/Comment?contentID=ViewBag.ContentId

Comment: I got it ,it because of @ in viewbag.thanks it works